# node-webkit - moving second window to a second or specific screen

Tags: javascript, node-webkit, nw.js

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26396168/nodewebkit-documentation-said-screen-will-work-but-its-getting-impossible-to) provided answer to move a main window to second screen. If an app has two windows. How do I move second window to second screen or a specific screen? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found solution here https://github.com/RSATom/WebChimera/issues/105. Code for second window

```js
var gui = require('nw.gui');
gui.Screen.Init();
win = gui.Window.get();
if (win.x < gui.Screen.screens[gui.Screen.screens.length -1].work_area.x) win.x = gui.Screen.screens[gui.Screen.screens.length -1].work_area.x + win.x;

var screenCB = {
    onDisplayAdded : function(screen) {
        win = gui.Window.get();
        if (win.x < screen.work_area.x) win.x = screen.work_area.x + win.x;
    }
};

gui.Screen.on('displayAdded', screenCB.onDisplayAdded);
```